# Python : 'int' object is not iterable Função Random

Tags: python, random, int

Estou tendo esse erro quando rodo o código.

Se eu defino `pos=(algum numero qualquer)` o código roda normalmente ,mas se eu uso essa função random da erro.

> 'int' object is not iterable na linha 20 a principio.

Onde estou errando? na função Deposito estou enviando y.sub=matriz de zeros.

```
import numpy as np
import random

def Deposito(x): 

    for i in range(16):
        pos=randint(0,15)
        D=(pos+1)%16;
        E=(pos+15)%16;
        h=0

        while h<30:

            if (x[h,D]==1 and x[h,pos]==0):
                x[h,pos]=1 
                break        
            elif (x[h,E]==1 and x[h,pos]==0):
                x=[h,pos]=1 
                break 
            elif (x[h,pos]==1):
                x[h-1,pos]=1 
                break
            h=h+1
            if h==29:
                x[h,pos]=1


class Amostra: 

    substrato=np.zeros((30,16))
    sub=substrato   

    y=Amostra()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é o motivo do erro mas aqui deveria ser:

```
pos = random.randint(0,15)
```

Mas creio que o erro esteja aqui:

```
# ...
elif (x[h,E]==1 and x[h,pos]==0):
    x=[h,pos]=1 
    break
# ...
```

Que deveria ser `x[h, pos] = 1`, não?

Comment: Muito obrigado . Total falta de atenção mesmo .

Comment: Agora  a mensagem de erro faz sentido até.